# vCPUs mapped to CPU on multiple servers

Tags: openstack

I have openstack deployed across multiple servers. Each server has 2 CPU, 8 Cores each, 16 threads each. If I turn hyper-threading on, how many max vCPUs can I use on my openstack deployment so that I don't overcommit any vCPUs for any VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hyperthreading***

I recommend against turning on hyperthreading in when working with KVM in general, however I am biased.  When hyperthreading and kvm were both young, there were many issues that cropped up around vcpu and hyperthreading.

For clarity, hyperthreading simply creates a soft-logical processor in the linux kernel in an effort to reach a higher efficiency in the cpu processing queue.

***Overcommitting, vCPUs and logical CPUs***

A vCPU is a virtual cpu allocated to a virtual machine.

A logical CPU is a CPU logically allocated to your host system's Linux kernel.

As seen with hyperthreading, sometimes the logical CPUs outnumber the physical CPUs or cores on the host.

You are technically overcommitting the moment you have more vcpu cores than physical cores.  Note how I said PHYSICAL cores, not logical CPUs.  What linux shows you in proc/cpuinfo may not be an accurate reflection of available physical cores, in part thanks to hyperthreading.

As kvm allocates vCPUs they are not set with any sort of CPU affinity by default.  What this means is, the vCPUs are going to whichever logical processor in linux seems to be most available at the time.  If someone kicks off a make 'MAKE=make -j64' World sort of job, you might see some pretty significant utilization spin up and begin to fire hose around whatever logical CPUs are most available at any given instruction set.

Now if you have an 8 physical core box, hosting 4 virtual machines, with 2 vCPUs a piece this is fine.  But think about what happens with hyperthreading enabled... now you have 16 logical CPUs, but only 8 cores.  What happens when you bring up 4 more virtual machines?  You run the risk of having virtual machines directly impacting resource availability to their neighbors.  This is technically overcommitting.

Don't overcommit if you don't have to.

Also consider the needs of the host.  You might want to set cpu_affinity on the host system when you perform CPU intensive actions and consider that physical core as dedicated to the HOST, and subtract it from the available ( max ) vCPU count available to VMs.

Learn how to set affinity's with taskset:

ref: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/taskset.1.html

***Max vCPU per VM***

As for cpu quotas, this is basically a function of your hypervisor not of OpenStack.  You'll want to handle that with a CFM and some careful planning.

For instance, RedHat tunes their own KVM packages:

> The maximum amount of virtual CPUs that is supported per guest varies
>   depending on which minor version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 you are
>   using as a host machine. The release of 6.0 introduced a maximum of
>   64, while 6.3 introduced a maximum of 160. Currently with the release
>   of 6.7, a maximum of 240 virtual CPUs per guest is supported.

ref: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Virtualization_Restrictions.html

Here is some info on tuning PER vm cpu / resource allocation

ref: http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUAllocation